# How to compare different Pokémon with the same CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am familiar with the [Pokémon GO Species/Moveset Analysis Tool](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fTrOFQ0pVdVTfcEJdqQBqqIaFe55oaryz1CpxWY7vV0/edit) spreadsheet, which is very helpful, when one wants to compare movesets of one Pokémon or to compare different Pokémon on the same level. But for the sake of efficient gym training, I would need to compare different Pokémon with the same CP. Let me give an example (to simplify things, let's ignore IV or attack types for now):

Let's assume, I have following three Pokémon:

1. Snorlax (Lick, Hyper Beam), level 15, CP 1250
2. Snorlax (Lick, Hyper Beam), level 7, CP 550
3. Raticate (Bite, Hyper Beam), level 15, CP 550

The spreadsheet enables me to compare #1 and #3, so even without understanding what all these ratings exactly mean, I can easily see that Snorlax is far superior to Raticate both defensively and offensively, which is something I would guess just after seeing their CP (1250 vs 550).

But assume, I need to train a gym with Pokémon around 1100 CP in it. To get maximum prestige, I would want to use Pokémon that has around 550 CP. Thus, I would need to compare #2 and #3, which are different levels, but the same CP.

Is there a way to use this spreadsheet so that it can do this kind of comparison? Or is there other spreadsheet/tool/website where I can do this comparison?

Comment: Since prestige is based on raw CP alone, it doesn't matter if you use #2 or #3, however, Snorlax has *much* more HP than Raticate, so it's the better choice.

Comment: It was just an example. I am looking for a way to do general comparison. Your approach (to simply compare HP of pokemons) doesn't work in general.

Comment: in general, whichever Pokemon has a lower level is the stronger Pokemon, if they have the same CP. Using common sense, a Snorlax would be a better option than an equal CP Raticate. A Lapras would be a better option than an equal CP Shellder. An Exeggutor would be a better choice than an equal CP Oddish. In all of these examples, the level of the first would be much lower than the level of the second if they have equal CP. Base stats would be the best way to see this definitively, though, so maybe check [here](https://thesilphroad.com/research)...

Comment: Also, simply comparing HP is a simple and quick way to pick. Only a handful of Pokemon have extraordinary HP levels in Pokemon Go (Lapras, Vaporeon, Snorlax, Wigglytuff, Kangaskhan, and Chansey). Of all of these, Chansey is by far the worst attacker and having any experience with the Pokemon series would tell you that Chansey is a defender, rather than an attacker, anyways. Also, despite its looks, Wigglytuff is no pushover.

Comment: Well, if it's really this simple (lower level = stronger pokemon) then it is great. And it is really helpful, even if it was just an approximation that works in 90% of cases or so. Thanks! Still, I'd like to keep looking for a way to compare pokemons more exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which one is objectively better, use [the Silph Road research page](https://thesilphroad.com/research).

Two Pokemon with the same CP tend to perform roughly the same, ignoring movesets and typing. However, Pokemon with exceptional values in some stats may outperform other species. For example, a Snorlax will typically last longer than a Raticate due to its very high HP and Defense.

I did a calculation via the Silph Road IV Rater to show this:

- A level 13.5 Raticate with CP 500 (roughly in the middle) can have between 53 and 61 HP.
- A level 6.0 Snorlax with CP 500 (on the high end) can have between 102 and 107 HP.

IVs aside, this low level Snorlax will most definitely tank more hits than the Raticate with equal CP. In the case where both know Hyper Beam, though, they are equally valid choices, since with STAB, Hyper Beam is the most powerful move in the game.

For another example, I'll compare Lapras and Cloyster, both Ice/Water types.

- A level 9.5 Cloyster with 500 CP (roughly mid-range) can have between 41 and 47 HP.
- A level 6.5 Lapras with 500 CP (roughly mid-range) can have between 87 and 92 HP.

Given Lapras' inherent tankiness, Lapras is a better choice than Cloyster.

If basing your decision HP alone doesn't settle it for you, look at the species' base stats on the link I provided above.

Comment: With regard to the very first advice. How exactly should the page be used? You mean that "SPECIES" tab? How can it help? Sorry if I am just dumb :)

Comment: @EulaliCumir yes, just use the Species Base Stats page. The scales give you an idea of what each species' strengths and weaknesses are.

Comment: Thanks, I know that page, but it doesn't help me. A pokemon with higher stats will have lower level if it should have same CP as a pokemon with lower stats. But level also matters when computing damage (otherwise lvl 1 Dragonite would be a better pick than a level 40 Pidgey or even Vaporeon), which is why I was asking.

Comment: @EulaliCumir level really doesn't matter for that computation. Level really is just a multiplier on the base stats + IVs. Each level increase raises the stats by a set number. Thus, with similar or the same CP, two Pokemon will have relatively similar stats as well. While a level 1 Dragonite will not be better than a level 40 Pidgey, a level 10 Dragonite very well could be. The reason Dragonite will not be a better choice than a Vaporeon much higher level than it is due to the fact that Vaporeon has a high CP cap, just like Dragonite.

Comment: @EulaliCumir the question you seem to be trying to ask is "When two Pokemon are of equal strength, which is stronger?" but the question is answered in the question itself. They are of equal strength, which is why the CP is the same. The different base stats cause the CP to be affected differently, though ATK is the biggest influence. Pokemon with slightly lower ATK than its peers but much higher HP and/or DEF will be about the same CP but you will notice a huge difference when battling with them. While the tanky Pokemon will not deal damage as fast, it will outlast the others.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. But here you hit the nail. Dragonite level 1 is weaker than Pidgey level 40, but Dragonite level 10 is (perhaps) stronger. 1) I am unable to extract this knowledge from that page, 2) what level are they about the same useful in gyms then?

Comment: @EulaliCumir, for this specific calculation, check the IV Rater. I did a couple comparisons in my answer already for Raticate v. Snorlax as well as Cloyster v. Lapras. For this one, a Pidgey can have, at most, 679 CP and 75 HP with 100% perfect IVs. At level 8, a 0% perfect Dragonite will have 691 CP and 68 HP. I'm not sure what exactly you'd want a level 40.0 Pidgey for though, as the Stardust and Candy cost would be astronomically high for how ridiculously useless that Pidgey would be... The reason Dragonite, Vaporeon, Lapras, etc. are good is that they have high CP for their levels always.

Comment: Exactly, with one minor detail - "When two Pokemons are of equal **CP**, which is stronger". CP is a terrible measurement of pokemon's usefulness. Otherwise, it would be kind of ideal. No matter what pokemon with 550 CP I get, I get the same results (provided they have same moveset and we ignore attack types). But if that was true, then it's contradiction to what you stated above about Snorlax being better than Raticate or Lapras better than Cloyster.

Comment: @EulaliCumir, you're misquoting me. I said strength. Strength is CP and HP. You keep ignoring what I have been saying about HP this whole time. HP doesn't factor into CP as much as ATK so a super high HP Pokemon could have a deceptively low CP (Chansey, for instance). Snorlax is objectively better than Raticate for a very large range of levels, as shown in my example, just as Lapras is objectively better than Cloyster for a large, albeit smaller, range. I'm not sure what you are still confused about at this point.

Comment: OK, sorry about misquoting you. It definitely wasn't intentional. HP having too small effect in CP is a news for me and now it's much clearer why you picked HP as a rule of thumb up in comments at my question. Perfect, thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: @EulaliCumir no worries. Hopefully it all makes sense now.

Comment: @EulaliCumir, I apologize, I went through numerous drafts before posting this answer and apparently I removed the formula for CP that I thought I'd left in there!! Look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t7r4d/exact_pokemon_cp_formula/) for the formula!